# What factors determine the duration of AR record creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, delayed-job

I'm trying to do some performance optimization of POST requests that include parameters for several (generally six) associated activerecord models, requiring new records to be inserted into several different tables on each request. Several models also have after filters that perform a number of tasks, some of which are handled asynchronously by delayed_job, which itself involves inserting records into the delayed_jobs table, so that they can be retrieved and processed offline by a delayed_job worker. All of this is in Rails production mode using Postgres on a Rackspace virtual private server.

Inspecting the SQL INSERT INTO statements in my log file, table insertions for my application data frequently take anywhere in the vicinity of a couple of hundred ms each. However the records inserted into the delayed_jobs table during the request cycle typically take less than 10ms.

Yet my models seem no more complex than delayed_job's model, e.g. I'm typically inserting 2-6 attributes on each record creation, most involving indexed foreign keys (some type strings for polymorphic models) plus a small number of other integer or string fields. Delayed_job insertions on the other hand involve 4 columns, consisting of 3 datetimes and a sometimes lengthy 'handler' text field. So on the face of it, the delayed_job records seem to be at least as complex as several of the application records I'm inserting but are at least an order of magnitude (typically 20-30x) faster.

So I'm trying to figure out what makes the difference between these two situations. In general what factors influence the duration of model insertions and why might delayed_job be inserting records so much faster than my application models?